# Animation will NOT stop running

Tags: android, animation

i have implemented an animation on one of my image views.  My problem is that the animation will NOT stop at all.  I call everything clearanimation i set it to null set it to cancel and it still wont stop.

```
public void tiltani(){
ImageView vault = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.vault2) ;
Animation tilt = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.tilt);

vault.startAnimation(tilt);
}
public void stopani() {
Animation tilt = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.tilt);
vault.clearAnimation();
vault.setAnimation(null);
tilt.cancel();
tilt.reset();
}
```

here is xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<rotate
android:fromDegrees="0"
android:toDegrees="6"
android:pivotX="50%"
android:pivotY="50%"
android:duration="500"
android:repeatCount="infinite"/>

<rotate
    android:fromDegrees="6"
    android:toDegrees="-2"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:duration="500"
    android:repeatMode="reverse"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    />
```

here is where i start it

```
   Intent intent1 = getIntent();

    if (intent1.hasExtra("id1")) {
        tiltani();
```

and i try to stop/cancel everything in an onclick method

```
 vault.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                vault.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(MainActivity.this, R.drawable.chestopen));
                stopani();
```

**update**

```
  Animation tilt = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.tilt);

if (intent1.hasExtra("id1")) {
        vault.startAnimation(tilt);



  vault.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

vault.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(MainActivity.this, 
R.drawable.chestopen));

                vault.setAnimation(null);
```

Comment: Maybe `android:repeatCount="infinite"`, in your XML file, is the cause of your problem. Try removing it

Comment: wouldn't canceling the animation stop it though

Comment: Put an integer value so, `infinite` is the cause of your problem

Comment: setting it to 10 did nothing it still will not stop.

Comment: seems like at this point it is something else

Comment: Remove  android:repeatCount="infinite" from animation xml . you know what infinite means ?

Comment: if you read the comments i tried changing it to an int and it still doing the same thing

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `vault.startAnimation(tilt);` to start your animation, and use `vault.setAnimation(null);` to stop your animation.

You have initialized **Animation** a second time in `stopani()` method. Your view initialization and animation initialization should be global.

Your code should be like this.

```
ImageView vault = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.vault2);           //Global variable
Animation tilt = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.tilt); //Global variable

public void tiltani(){
    vault.startAnimation(tilt);
}
public void stopani() {
    vault.clearAnimation();
    vault.setAnimation(null);
    tilt.cancel();
    tilt.reset();
}
```

Hope, It will help you.. :)

Comment: my stopani method calls setAnimation(null) already but it dosent do anything. and that happens inside an onclick method

Comment: now i have to tried this one.. just you can try.. it will work. I think your re-initializing unwanted things.. may be it was a reason.

Comment: Just you have to give    android:clickable="true"    on your Imageview in XML layout..

Comment: the image view works just fine already it was already in place before i added this

Comment: could you give your remote access